# SQL Server Agent error handling - try, transaction, catch

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, transactions, jobs, agent

I'm working in MS SQL Server trying to move some data from our live environment into an archive area. I have written my code and it goes something like this:

```
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
        copy data to archive
        another step to change data in a different table
        delete archived data from original source
    COMMIT
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK
END CATCH
```

This all seems fine and works, either committing or does a rollback as I expect it to, when I have my code and run it as a script (F5).

What I'm now looking at doing is setting it up as a SQL Server Agent job to run daily.

Normally I would get the job to send a notification on failure however I'm wondering if the TRY/CATCH clause would mean that the SQL Server Job always considers the script to have run successfully and as such not report a failure.

Would the job report failure if it hits a rollback statement?

Is there something I can insert after the ROLLBACK to say failure and not end the CATCH?

If I remove the TRY/CATCH from the code I'm certain that the job would report failure but I doubt it would rollback any changes. What I don't want to happen is for the job to report a failure but for the process to have got partway through and not rolled back.

Would the job automatically rollback on failure, if not is there something I can add to get it to rollback on faillure?

Could I set up a different step in the job with just ROLLBACK in it and end that step reporting failure? Would the step know that I was rolling back what happened in a previous step?

Comment: THROW is the word..

Comment: Agree with @dean. But you could also use `sp_send_dbmail` inside your catch to notify the failure.